# Nonexistent service gets a start control?

Tags: windows-server-2003, service, server-crashes

I've got a pair of servers that both log an event "The cpuz135 service was successfully sent a start control." but cpu-z isn't installed on either machine. I can't find the service listed in Windows' service manager console or on the command line with 'sc query type= service'.

Both servers are Win 2003 and like to crash after this event has been logged. Where else could this be coming from?

Comment: Looks like you need to do a registry dive.  Search on `cpuz135` and eliminate the keys you get back.  (You know, carefully, and after taking a backup and blahblahblah.)

Answer (score 5):

That service is probably related to this:

http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

You can delete the service by hacking it out of the registry or by running

sc delete **Service Name** from the command prompt

Comment: I found what I believe to be the corresponding registry key and removed it. Hopefully it will stop appearing.